# Проблема при переходе в полноэкранный режим (C# WinForms)?

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть окно программы, в ней стоит кнопка, которая переводит окно программы в полноэкранный режим. При нажатии на Esc программа переводится в оконный режим. Сделано все как в документации.
При нажатии на кнопку:

```
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        this.TopMost = true;
```

При нажатии на Esc:

```
         this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.Sizable;
         this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
         this.TopMost = false;
```

Скажу сразу что все работает, но есть 1 проблема. Когда перевожу в полноэкранный режим с оконного состояния - все нормально, программа покрывает весь экран вместе с меню "Пуск". Когда перевожу в полноэкранный режим с развернутого состояния - программа не может скрыть меню "Пуск" и в итоге сдвигается вверх. Я конечно мог бы при помощи WinApi задать команду для скрытия меню "пуск". Но просто если от оконного все нормально происходит, почему так не происходит от развернутого? Скажите в чем проблема?

Comment: Хм. У вас в развёрнутом состоянии `WindowState` **уже** равен `FormWindowState.Maximized`, поэтому эта часть может быть работает не так. Может быть, попробуйте поменять его на `Normal`, а затем снова на `Maximized`?

Comment: Точно! Вы оказались правы. Спасибо!

Comment: Отлично, тогда перенесу в ответ. // Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в развёрнутом состоянии `WindowState` уже равен `FormWindowState.Maximized`, поэтому эта часть может работать не так.

Попробуйте поменять его сначала на `Normal`, а затем снова на `Maximized`.